Let $a$, $b$, and $c$ be positive integers. Prove that $\left( \frac{(a+b+c)^4(ab+bc+ca)}{abc} \right)^{\frac{1}{5}} \geq 3$
Problem:
Prove that for every positive integers $a$, $b$, and $c$ the following inequality holds.
$\left( \frac{(a+b+c)^4(ab+bc+ca)}{abc} \right)^{\frac{1}{5}} \geq 3$

My Approach
I started by analyzing the given expression:
$$\left( \frac{(a+b+c)^4(ab+bc+ca)}{abc} \right)^{\frac{1}{5}} \geq 3$$
We are given that $a$, $b$, and $c$ are positive integers. At first glance, it seems that the AM-GM inequality will be useful for handling the sum and product terms. I tried breaking down the problem.
Applying AM-GM to $a$, $b$, and $c$
Using the AM-GM inequality for the terms $a$, $b$, and $c$, I got:
$$ \frac{a+b+c}{3} \geq \sqrt[3]{abc} $$
Multiplying both sides by 3,:
$$ a+b+c \geq 3\sqrt[3]{abc} $$
This is useful because it gives a lower bound for $a+b+c$, which might help simplify part of the expression later.
Investigating $ab + bc + ca$
Next, I need to deal with the term $ab + bc + ca$. This term represents a symmetric sum of products, and I think I might need to apply another inequality here, possibly Cauchy-Schwarz or another symmetric inequality. But I’m not entirely sure how to relate this to the full expression, or how it connects with $abc$ in the denominator.
I tried thinking about bounding $ab + bc + ca$ using AM-GM as well, but I can't seem to figure out how it works in this context. I know this inequality is true, but I’m struggling with the next step and how to manipulate the terms further to arrive at the conclusion.
It seems I am not getting anywhere.
Can anyone please tell how can I arrive at the final expression.

Why did you consider only integers?

Here's a solution using AM-GM.
As noticed by you, $$\frac{a+b+c}{3} \geq \sqrt[3]{abc}$$
which after cubing and multiplying by both sides by $a+b+c$ can be written as:
$$(a+b+c)^4 \geq 27abc(a+b+c)$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{(a+b+c)^4}{abc} \geq 27(a+b+c)$$
Multiply both sides of the above by $ab+bc+ca$,
$$\Rightarrow \frac{(a+b+c)^4(ab+bc+ca)}{abc} \geq 27(ab+bc+ca)(a+b+c)$$
Now note that by using the above equation and directly applying AM-GM in the terms $ab,bc,ca$,
$$(a+b+c)(ab+bc+ca) \geq 9abc$$
Which means,
$$\frac{(a+b+c)^4(ab+bc+ca)}{abc} \geq 27(ab+bc+ca)(a+b+c) \geq 243abc \geq 243 = 3^5$$
(as $a,b,c$ are positive integers, their minimum value is at $a=b=c=1$ in which case $abc=1$
Which finally gives us
$$\frac{(a+b+c)^4(ab+bc+ca)}{abc} \geq 3^5 $$
or equivalently,
$$\left( \frac{(a+b+c)^4(ab+bc+ca)}{abc} \right)^{\frac{1}{5}} \geq 3$$

You have the right approach. You might want to look instead into the AM-HM inequality.
The Harmonic Mean is
$$HM(a,b,c) = \dfrac{3}{\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}}.$$
Note also that
$$\begin{align*}\frac{1}{HM} &= \dfrac{\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}}{3} \\ &=\frac{bc + ac + ab}{3abc}.\end{align*}$$
I'm sure you can take it from here.

Yup I got it, that makes it a bit easier than AM-GM.

Here's one way to do it (nearly) "all in one". It's the same AGM application as before but all combined.
For any $\alpha>0$, we have
$$abc = ((ab) (bc) (ca))^{\alpha/3} (abc)^{(3-2\alpha)/3} \le (\frac{ab+bc+ca}{3})^{\alpha}(\frac{a+b+c}{3})^{3-2\alpha}.$$
Pick $\alpha =\frac 12$ so ratio of exponents on the RHS is 1:4, exactly  as in original expression, and plug this into our expression to obtain
$$ \frac{(a+b+c)^4 (ab+bc+ ca)}{abc} \ge (a+b+c)^{4-1}\sqrt{ab+bc+ca}\times 3^{3/2}\ge 3^{3+\frac 12 + \frac{3}{2}}=3^5.$$
